# PHP's apache_setenv function causes 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache

```
apache_setenv ( 'no-gzip', 1 )
```

I'm trying to disable gzip for a certain page's output, but only that page. This works fine on testing servers, but not the production server, which is running the same thing (CentOS and Apache), works on Ubuntu though.

Anyway, do you know why? Or is there some other alternative?

I was thinking of using ob_start () to put all output in a buffer, and then unzip it myself with a PHP function then call ob_end_flush ()... or would it not be gzipped until right before Apache sends it to the client?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is anything showing up in Apache's error log when you get the 500?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that php is running as a module rather than a cgi-extension and safe mode must be disabled.